# Where does 'mobile' keyword in the useragent come from in chromium?

Tags: android, chromium

I'm confused that on mobile devices(`phone`) on Android system, the **useragent** of chromium based browser(eg `webview`) have `Mobile` keyword, but on some mobile devices(eg `tablets`) it does not exist, so where is distinguished in the `chrmoium` code?

The mobile devices which have the `Mobile` keyword:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.23 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check and reference the [DeviceUtils.java](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/DeviceUtils.java) and [aw_content_client.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/common/aw_content_client.cc?q=aw_content_client.cc&dr) in chromium source, it will check the device type by `DeviceFormFactor.isTablet()` in [DeviceUtils.java](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/android/java/src/org/chromium/content/browser/DeviceUtils.java) to decide whether it need to add the `Mobile` keyword, and set the `Mobile` keyword in [aw_content_client.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/android_webview/common/aw_content_client.cc?q=aw_content_client.cc&dr), hopes this information can help you:

```
//DeviceUtils.java
package org.chromium.content.browser;

import android.content.Context;

import org.chromium.base.CommandLine;
import org.chromium.content.common.ContentSwitches;
import org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor;

/**
 * A utility class that has helper methods for device configuration.
 */
public class DeviceUtils {

    /**
     * Appends the switch specifying which user agent should be used for this device.
     * @param context The context for the caller activity.
     */
    public static void addDeviceSpecificUserAgentSwitch(Context context) {
        if (DeviceFormFactor.isTablet(context)) {
            CommandLine.getInstance().appendSwitch(ContentSwitches.USE_MOBILE_UA);
        }
    }
}



   //aw_content_client.cc
   std::string GetUserAgent() {
  // "Version/4.0" had been hardcoded in the legacy WebView.
  std::string product = "Version/4.0 " + GetProduct();
  if (base::CommandLine::ForCurrentProcess()->HasSwitch(
        switches::kUseMobileUserAgent)) {
    product += " Mobile";
  }
  return content::BuildUserAgentFromProductAndExtraOSInfo(
          product,
          GetExtraOSUserAgentInfo());
}
```